# Xamarin.Forms app works in debug but crash in release on ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm a new xamarin developer and this is my first post :)
So, I'm develop a xamarin forms application with prism framework. Everything works in debug mode but in release mode the app crash on start on ios.

This is my OnInitialized function

```
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (DataContext.GetContext().CurrentUser == null)
            {
                if ((await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(LoginScreen))).Exception is Exception e)
                    throw e;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainScreen")).Exception is Exception e)
                    throw e;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"[ERR] in {nameof(OnInitialized)}");
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(AppResources.Error_Label);
        }
```

However when I debug in release mode with check "Enable debugging" i catch an exception that said "navigation uri is empty". I dont understand why.

[Debug option in release mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwt3S.png)

All advice is welcome, thanks in advance

Comment: please do NOT post code as images

Comment: excuse me, i just edit my post

Comment: Without a reproduction nobody can really see enough about your app to tell you why you are getting an exception. That said the code you have here is really horrible. There is ZERO reason to be throwing an exception there. Simply await the result and pass the result to another method to handle an exception is it's not null.